# PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {numpy==1.20.3(wheel)}

Tags: amazon-web-services, sam

`sam build` fails with the following error:

Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {numpy==1.20.3(wheel)}

I tried `sam build --use-container`, but get the same error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

apparently, the new numpy 1.20.3 released May 10 2021 is not compatible. I specified the previous version of numpy in my requirements.txt file, and it worked just fine.

```
$cat requirements.txt
numpy==1.20.2
```